# How to amplify a 2MHz signal?

Tags: high-frequency

I am working on ultrasound sensors. At the receiving end I have a 2MHz signal of 80mV p-p.
I need to amplify it at least by 10 times. Please suggest an appropriate method.

Additionally, I need to know if normal opamps work with a 2MHz signal? If not, are separate ICs available for that?

Comment: people have suggested OPAmps, this is correct, look at the AD603. I think that should fit your needs nicely.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, an opamp will work for your application.

There is no such thing as a "standard opamp" - there are opamps, all with different parameters. You'll need to spec one out for your application. While doing so, make sure you understand the implications of [gain-bandwidth product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gain%E2%80%93bandwidth_product) on opamp circuits.

Answer (score 1):

You will need several stages of opamps, perhaps some implemented as filters with a little gain, wither passive filters (high pass and bandpass) between each stage.  I would also suggest including a PGA (Programmable Gain Amplifier) as you will need to alter the gain to compensate for differences in transducers and the coupling medium.

There are a vast range of opamp parameters that you should consider for each stage, it may be such that a single type of opamp will not be suitable for all stages.

A rule of thumb is to get as much low noise (i.e. heavily filterd) gain at your front end with a high input impedance as you can afford, then later sections can have a reasonable gain without just amplifying the noise introduced by the circuit itself.

If you don't filter at regular stages then DC and the local radio station will be amplified too, saturating both these and your later circuit sections.

IIRC the last one of these I designed had five sections with buffers (gain==1) before tuned filters (low Q) so that the filter does not load the prior section.  Though this had a system gain of -20 to +70 dB (adjustable) which is probably more than you need.
I used JFET inputs in a follower configuration (gain<1) for high impedance and to protect the later opamps.  Also clamp your inputs as if you ding a transducer you get hundreds of volts out of it.